# Usage of Netty WRITE_SPIN_COUNT

Tags: netty

I would like to understand the usage of Netty's Channel Option "WRITE_SPIN_COUNT".
What is the effect of setting this value higher or lower than the default( 16 ). Should this be set at all.? 
This is what i got from the Netty documentation but wasn't clear why and when should we set this value : http://netty.io/4.0/api/io/netty/channel/DefaultChannelConfig.html#getWriteSpinCount()
As per the documentation it says : 
Returns the maximum loop count for a write operation until WritableByteChannel.write(ByteBuffer) returns a non-zero value. It is similar to what a spin lock is used for in concurrency programming. It improves memory utilization and write throughput depending on the platform that JVM runs on. The default value is 16.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The write spin count is used to control how many times the underlying `socket.write(...)` is called per Netty write operation. Keep in mind that a write from Netty's buffers to the underlying sockets may not transfer all data in one try. There is a balance between how much time of the I/O thread can be spent attempting to fully write a single buffer, and if that buffer is not fully written then I/O thread must register for the write event and be woken up when the underlying socket is writable. The later operation can be expensive because *usually* the socket is writable and the I/O thread will be woken up as soon as it attempts to wait on the select mechanism.  What I describe can bee seen in [NioSocketChannel](https://github.com/netty/netty/blob/4.0/transport/src/main/java/io/netty/channel/nio/AbstractNioByteChannel.java#L203).

My advice for these types of configuration options is if you are observing a performance issue then benchmark for your use-case, or leave the default value. Benchmarks may reveal that your problem lies elsewhere, or at least will help you understand the impacts of changing this value for your specific use case.

Comment: thanks for the reply. Now i understand what this is for.